# How to seed graph generator in python-igraph?

Tags: python-2.7, igraph

Is there any way to seed the following Watts-Strogatz graph generated using python-igraph,  so that each time I run the script I get the same realization of SW graph ?

```
import igraph
graph = igraph.Graph.Watts_Strogatz(1, N, nei, p)
```

where `N` is the number of nodes, `nei` the number of connected neighbors, and `p` the rewiring probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

igraph uses the built-in RNG of Python so you can seed that:

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: random.seed(1234)
In [3]: g=Graph.Watts_Strogatz(1, 100, 2, 0.25)
In [4]: random.seed(1234)
In [5]: g2=Graph.Watts_Strogatz(1, 100, 2, 0.25)
In [6]: g.get_edgelist() == g2.get_edgelist()
Out[6]:  True
```