# Python-igraph community_infomap method give different cluster result each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, igraph, network-analysis

When I run `community_infomap` using `python-igraph` package it gives different community result each time. I know it relates to the parameter randomly generates in this algorithm. So I wonder whether this method provides a parameter to set that result can be stable each time? For example, the seed.

I've searched this in the [documentation](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_infomap), but it seems that it only provides three parameters:
`edge_weights` - the name of an edge attribute or a list containing edge weights.
`vertex_weights` - name of a vertex attribute or a list containing vertex weights. and `trials` - the number of attempts to partition the network.

What can I do to achieve it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `community_infomap` from `python-igraph` is a stochastic algorithm by nature. To produce reproducible output for it (and possibly other stochastic algorithms, such as graph generation), you can initialize the random number generator by python's built-in RNG

```
In [1]: import random
In [2]: random.seed(11)
```

source:
[answer from the developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718008/how-to-seed-graph-generator-in-python-igraph)